# Anime series or movie where boy gets the horns of the devil

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I already asked this but I didn't register so here we go again. I can’t remember much, as I saw it when I was younger (around 2006).  But this boy acquires "the devil's horns" and it gives him powers.  Also when he flies he leaves like gold dust particles in the air. I'm pretty sure he went to a school too and it was a crow in the school's yard that told him about his horns. Any help?

Comment: 2 things:  a) I don't believe you are supposed to repost questions in order to bring attention to them, there are other ways b) you should [merge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts

Comment: Welcome (back) to the site! @eshier is right that you generally shouldn't repost questions; in this case, since you can't access the old question with your unregistered account, I've closed and deleted that one in favour of this one. Good luck finding the anime! :-)

Comment: Where does the boy keep the devil's horns after he acquires them?  In his sock drawer?  In a shoe box?  In a safe deposit box?  It would be hard to keep them safe from being repossessed by the devil.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [Blue Exorcist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Exorcist), in that:

- The protagonist learns he's the son of Satan and gains horns (as well as fangs and a tail)
- The protagonist gains powers
- The protagonist goes to school
- There is a crow character, [Gufu](http://aonoexorcist.wikia.com/wiki/Gufu)

He doesn't leave gold dust particles in the air when he flies, but he does leave blue energy trails in the air.

However, the series came out in 2011, which doesn't quite fit your timeline. Are you sure it wasn't a little later?

Comment: That was going to be my answer if you hadn't gotten to it first. :-)